# Pontos sensíveis dentro da imagem

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma imagem do corpo humano, e gostaria fazer seleções conforme clicado na parte do corpo (exemplo: joelho, coxa, etc). Tentei utilizar o método de mapa de imagens, porém sem sucesso. Alguém possui alguma sugestão de como é possível realizar este procedimento?

Comment: Melhor é usar map mesmo. O Dreamweaver faz isso com facilidade. Mas tem uns sites online tb que oferecem esse serviço.

Comment: e como é possível fazer a relação do map com o banco de dados? Pois o resultado do local escolhido, precisa ser lançado juntamente a um "relatório". Existe alguma função que auxilie neste processo?

Comment: basta enviar ao banco as coordenadas do mapa

Comment: então no caso eu teria que criar um banco de dados com todos os locais e após isso fazer um INNER JOIN para apresentá-lo no relatório? Você poderia me auxiliar com qual código eu faço o envio das coordenadas para o BD?

Comment: No banco vc pode criar uma tabela com o nome da região, as coordenadas e o link... se quiser pode incluir o "title", que é quando passa o mouse e mostra uma mensagem

Comment: Quando criar todo o mapa, vc pode pegar todos os dados via JS e enviar pro banco

Comment: Um Javascript ou jQuery (mais fácil) faria o serviço perfeitamente.

Comment: Como vc quer mapear todo o corpo humano, teria que incluir na pergunta a imagem que quer mapear, e listar TODAS as regiões que deseja.

Comment: perfeito, como faço isso utilizando o jQuery?

Comment: O jQuery seria apenas para capturar os dados. O mapa tem que ser feito no HTML

Comment: Tenho uma ideia que pode te ajudar, e ainda vai ficar responsivo. Vc cria um Grid, tipo uma folha quadriculada, e no Container onde o grid está dentro vc coloca a imagem que quer como background. Veja esse imagem como apenas exemplo: http://moylanryan.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/alignment_grid.268234235_std.jpg . Com o Grid vc pode dar nome a cada um dos quadrinhos. Link sobre o Grid CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas